# gem [Ruby] connecting through webproxy [windows]

Tags: php, ruby, windows, xampp, rubygems

I'm asking this age-old question on how go through your proxy when using ruby gem.

i tried setting the env variable `HTTP_PROXY`:

```
HTTP_PROXY=myusername:password@proxy.com:8080
```

but this does not work.

```
> gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
    bad URI(is not URI?): http://myusername:password@proxy.com:8080
```

i tried using adding the `tcp://` at the start but it shows `http://tcp://` in the error message, so i assumed that was wrong too.

So, i tried an automatic connect via php using this code:

```
<?php
$path = 'http://rubygems.org/';

$auth = base64_encode('myusername:password');

file_put_contents('proxy.log', 'POST::', FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('proxy.log', print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('proxy.log', 'GET::', FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('proxy.log', print_r($_GET, true), FILE_APPEND);

$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'content' => http_build_query($_GET),
        'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.com:8080',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth"
    )
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$sFile = file_get_contents($path, false, $cxContext);

header('Content-type: application/gzip');
echo $sFile;
```

and incase it is trying to get a specific file, i handled it using apache.

```
.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond $1 !^$
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# Options -Indexes
```

but still i get this error.

```
> gem sources -ahttp://mylocalhost/ror-proxy/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
not in gzip format
```

Any ideas?

Comment: HTTP_PROXY needs a full HTTP URL. Try `HTTP_PROXY=http://myusername:password@proxy.com:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed PHP proxy now.

when adding a new source gem sends out

> specs_4_8_gz

notice that it that `_` represents `.`(dot). all you need to do is replace it. note that this is only done once. other gems will be sent out as their proper file name.

should look something like this.

```
if (empty($_GET['_p'])) {
    header('Content-type: text/html');
} else {
    header('Content-type: application/gzip');

    $item = $_GET['_p'];
    $item = '.gz' == substr($item, -3) ? $item: str_replace('_', '.', $item);
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $item . '"');
    $path .= $item;
}
```

my full script will be posted on github.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy servers, particularly authenticating proxy servers can throw a monkey wrench in all sorts of automatic update services.  Unfortunately, `gem` does not properly deal with the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.  In short, it doesn't know what to do with a BasicAuthentication response from a server--even though it tries.

Long story short, you'll have to set up a local proxy server that takes care of navigating through the proxy.  It can't do anything that performs any transformations (like decompressing a compressed stream).

The `myusername:password@company.com:8080` construct is not a valid URL.  I know that it is a shortcut for windows authenticating proxy servers, but only the portion after the `@` symbol is a valid URL.

Check out this FAQ: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/15

The problem is common enough.

Comment: Minor correction: Gem does basic auth, but it doesn't do NTLM authorization, as per your FAQ reference.

Comment: thanks @berin for your answer. I actually read that document before. the #apserver, which was a suggestion in that document, seems to be a dead project now.  are the any other alternatives?